# PHP code not outputting properly

Tags: php, html

I'm working with PHP and HTML, but I have an issue popping up whenever I write some PHP code. An example of this is as follows:

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Hello?</h2>";
$var = 5;
echo "You have $var minutes to go.";
?>
```

What this ends up outputting on screen is:

```
Hello?"; $var = 5; echo "You have $var minutes to go."; ?>
```

But what I want to happen is this:
    Hello? You have 5 minutes to go.

Is there something I'm forgetting to do?  It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I add the HTML preamble, or if I put a tag like

around the second echo line. Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT: Apparently I have failed to parse PHP correctly. This computer is new and I have XAMPP installed on it, but nothing else. Did I miss something I needed in order to use PHP?

Comment: I get the output. ` Hello? You have 5 minutes to go.`

Comment: It doesn't print the first `echo` ?

Comment: Try removing the `?` and check again and see what it outputs. Mean the `?` after Hello. Maybe it is closing your php tag or something

Comment: Are you actually running this on a web server, or just attempting to open a .php file in a local browser?

Comment: Michael Berkowski, at the moment it's just on my local computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like if the php code wasn't interpreted.

Make sure to have the code in a file with a filename ending with `.php` and that PHP is installed/enabled on your server.

Comment: If it isn't interpreted, how come the `<?php echo` part is not printed out on the screen?

Comment: @WebNovice this part is interpreted as a html tag. That's why it isn't visible in browser (you'll find it in source code)

Comment: 5 upvotes for this? :O, Ive posted upvotes longer then my arm :(

Comment: Thanks for that. The file is saved and uploaded as a .php file. To be precise, it's:
    file:///C:/my_folder/test.php
I may have forgotten to install something first. This is a new computer I am working with, and I just set up XAMPP and Notepad++.

Comment: @SamOfloinn Then you should make attention to access the file via xampp and not directly via the file system. (something that begins with `http://localhost/...`)

Answer (score 2):

The PHP isn't being parsed properly.

- Make sure you are saving your files as .php
- If you are running this locally through WAMP the make sure to use localhost in your URL because if your URL looks like this `file:///C:/wamp/www/index.php` then that is incorrect.
- I think CakePHP uses .ctp files so that could also be an issue
- You can setup Apache to interpret any file extension as PHP

Answer (score 0):

make php and html different.so things become much easier.
try like this:

```
<h2>Hello?</h2>
<?php
$var = 5;
?>
You have <?php echo $var;?> minutes to go.
```

Comment: this really isn't the answer to the question; that's just a coding style advice.